# Fedora 36 Virtualbox 6.1 Kernel driver not installed

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

VM in VirtualBox wouldn't launch displaying this issue:

[image]

I don't know how to resolve it.

Fedora 36 KDE
Virtualbox 6.1

Comment: Did you try the proposed thing? And: what happened, specifically?

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106307 6.1.34 is not compatible with kernel 5.18, you need to install a test build

Comment: Thanks, test build works fine.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Please don't add images of error messages, copy their wording too, so it can be searched on by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualbox 6.1.34 is not compatible with kernel 5.18.

A test build from [VirtualBox test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) is required.

(Builds>Latest 6.1.x test builds>Linux 64-bit)